# How does a client display the value of a server-side variable that is constantly changing?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

There is a location on my homepage (i.e., in my index.html) that I'd like to display a server-side global variable called `serverVariable`.  Note that `serverVariable` is constantly changing based off of server-side code running nodejs (i.e., `serverVariable` is a javascript object).

Unfortunately, I can't just place `serverVariable` in my index.html since it (i.e., the client) has no idea what it is.  Is there a simple way to pass `serverVariable` to the client so that I can place it in my index.html and have it constantly update depending upon what is going on in the server-side nodejs?

Comment: don't use ajax polling, use something persistent like socket.io.

Answer (score 1):

Using socket.io you can establish a persistent connection between the client and server. With that connection you can notify the client of any of your variable's changes.
A simple example could be:

On the server side :

```
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
io.on('connection', function() {
    //When client connects for the first time, send him the value immediately
    socket.emit('new_value', serverVariable);
});

//Everytime you change the value, send it to all the clients connected using:
io.emit('new_value', serverVariable);
```

On the client side :

```
var socket = io();
socket.on('new_value', function(serverVariable) {
    //Display it the way you want!
});
```

This example should fit your case if `serverVariable` is a "simple" object, i.e. an object you can directly convert to json. And also if the nodejs server is the server serving the homepage, otherwise you need to adapt the first line.

See http://socket.io/docs/ for more documentation about socket.io.

Comment: So as presented, `socket.on('new_value', function(serverVariable) {});` returns the current server-side value of `serverVariable`?

Comment: Socket.IO is actually event based. In this basic example. The server is sending `new_value`events (using `emit()`). The data send along the event is `serverVariable`. The client, in the code sample you quoted, is binding a function which will be executed whenever he receive a `new_value` event. 
This is not a way to request a variable's value from the server, but rather the server keeping all the clients up to date with the variable changes whenever they occur.

Comment: You could also choose another solution, which could be the clients asking the value whenever needed. But I understood that you want them to be up to date all the time. So this is the best solution in my opinion

Comment: How does one get that value on the client side?  If `serverVariable` is a global variable on the server side, can one just get the value on the client side by referring to the variable `serverVariable`?

Comment: If you look closely to the code I've given to you, on the client side, `serverVariable`'s scope is limited to the anonymous function binded to the `new_value` event. So you need to make it global if you want to refer it from elsewhere, e.g. by adding `globalServerVariable = serverVariable;` into the anonymous function.